# Trying to perform a click when "touch to beam" are on screen

Tags: android, nfc

Now I'm trying some tests to erase the actual "touch to beam" in NFC android shares, I try a lot of thing, like to control the "on touch" returning false, use thread with a timer to launch a click on the activity... and nothing, it's not response.

Some have any crazy Idea to make this task? without hack the firmware.
May I try to take all the views on screen, and try to figure out the one to perform a click?!

I take some days with test, and don't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I´m just beginning... but the "touch to beam" screen is another activity, an external activity, so you can not implement any method to control the onTouch event in this activity out of your control...

I´m also thinking about how to skip this "touch to beam"... no result for now!